# UIWebView - adjust on rotate?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiwebview, rotation

I have a UIWebView which loads a url. In MobileSafari this webpage will adjust  when the handset is rotated to the landscape position. In my UiWebView it just stays in portrait - is the a property I need to add to allow this to occur?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your `shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceRotation:` method to respond to the rotations needed. I have tested this and it works perfectly.

Comment: - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
 return YES;
}
This does not appear to do the trick? Any ideas?

Comment: It works for me in the iPhone simulator, if it doesn't work with the device, then i don't know what is going on..do you have the autosize properties set right? (e.g. flexible width/height)

Comment: Is it to do with it being a Tab Bar application? All the properties appear to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Is your top level UIViewController handling rotations (allowing them in the shouldAutorotate delegate) for its view (and thus for all subviews, including your web view)?